# Filter for honeycomb optimized apps

Tags: google-play-store, 3.0-honeycomb

Is there anyway to filter only for honeycomb optimized apps no market? I have a Motorola Xoom and wants to filter for all apps that looks good on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best you can do at this point is to use the "Featured Tablet Apps" page in the Market (this may be region-limited, it seems). [The web version](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_tablet_featured) seems to have more apps listed than the tablet section on Honeycomb's Market app.

You could also log into the Market website and filter searches based on whether or not the apps are compatible with your device (the Xoom, in this case), but the fact that they're compatible doesn't mean they're "optimized" for tablet so I suppose that's not quite the same.

For games you could also install Nvidia's [Tegra Zone](http://www.nvidia.com/object/tegra-zone.html) app, but it's technically just designed for anything optimized for Tegra chips (so the Atrix would be included but is not a tablet form factor). Most of the games seem to be made with larger devices in mind, though.

Comment: The market link you send me results in a not found here in brazil =(. For games I already use Tegra Zone app that is very good.

Comment: @Luiz: Can you get to the web version of the Market at all in Brazil? Should be https://market.android.com/?hl=pt_BR for the Brazilian Portuguese version (I think?) or just https://market.android.com for the main page.

Comment: I do have access to market here but when a try to access the https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_tablet_featured url I get a not found error. Probably this feature for filtering table apps isn't available here.

Comment: @Luiz: That's a really strange decision. I wonder why Google did that :-/ So you don't get a "Featured Tablet" apps tab on the main site, either? Here's a screenshot of what it looks like for me: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16958605/featured_tablet.png

Comment: I don't have this tab on my market http://dl.dropbox.com/u/137636/market.png Even if I change the market language to english I'm not able to see this tab